# How to close window after PHP code is executed?

Tags: javascript, php

I have two problems:

1. How do I close the window once I Have executed my PHP code which is a simple save textbox values to database?
2. How do I get my text boxes to align so they perfectly aligned currently one is more indented than the other [<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/TGLzN)?

Here's the PHP code that saves data into my database once saved I want the current window to close:

```
<form name="Permit" id="Permit" action="<?php echo JURI::current(); ?>" method="post">
    Permit or Deny: <input align= center  type="text" name="Permit_or_Deny" value=""><br>
    Level <input type="text" name="Level" value=""><br>
    <p><input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Permit Or Deny Submit Buutton" /></p>
</form>
        
     
<?
if ((isset($_POST['Permit_or_Deny'])) || (isset($_POST['Level']))) {
    //first name or last name set, continue-->
    $Permit_or_Deny = $_POST['Permit_or_Deny'];
    $Level          = $_POST['Level'];
    
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "INSERT INTO tp_newedit (Permit_or_Deny, Level) VALUES ('" . $Permit_or_Deny . "','" . $Level . "');";
    
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->query();
} else {
    echo '<h4>One Field Is Required!</h4>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Opps didnt think of that, fiddled added

Comment: added answer, you can change width accordingly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For first part -

```
<form name="Permit" id="Permit" action="<?php echo JURI::current(); ?>" method="post">

    <div class="label" style="display:inline-block;width:200px"> Permit or Deny: </div><input align= center  type="text" name="Permit_or_Deny" value=""/><br>
        <div class="label" style="width:200px;display:inline-block;"> Level </div> <input type="text" name="Level" value=""><br>

        <p><input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Permit Or Deny Submit Buutton" /></p>
    </form>
```

For second part, place this on server side code-

```
<?php    
    /* ... SQL EXECUTION TO UPDATE DB ... */

    echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Where it says window.close
Do i need to replace window with my page? Eg "<script>google.com.close();</script>";

or is that completely wrong and just i leave it?

Comment: It should be  same as I wrote. Place on server side code.

Comment: @user3403327 as i said, upvote and accept it for others to know that it worked

Comment: Ive tired it says I need a reputation of 15?

Answer (score 4):

Try `window.close()` of JavaScript:-

```
<?

if ((isset($_POST['Permit_or_Deny'])) || (isset($_POST['Level']))) {
    //first name or last name set, continue-->
    $Permit_or_Deny = $_POST['Permit_or_Deny'];
    $Level          = $_POST['Level'];

    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "INSERT INTO tp_newedit (Permit_or_Deny, Level) VALUES ('" . $Permit_or_Deny . "','" . $Level . "');";

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->query();

    echo  "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "window.close();";
    echo "</script>";
} else {
    echo '<h4>One Field Is Required!</h4>';
}

?>
```